# Which universe is Future Trunks from?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

Universe 6 and universe 7 are twin universes

If Earth didn't have life in Universe 6(Champa's universe). From where does Trunks come from? He couldn't have come from other Universe because they aren't twin universe.

If Trunks has come from alternate timeline of Universe 7, how did  an evil Goku come? He should have died of that heart virus?

Edit: Trunks has come from an alternate timeline of Universe 7.

And if Evil Goku is from Universe 6, how does TRUNKS know about him?

Comment: who is evil goku? also, why do you think that trunks was probably from an alternate universe, he is from the future, and he altered the timeline. Infact, as i recall, there was a spinoff about the Kai of time getting mad at him for altering the timeline and even recruited him to help her out (apparently by claiming it was taboo to build a time machine, let alone use it)

Answer (score 2):

The Future Trunks Arc hasn't been aired yet, the story hasn't been told, how do we know the plot?

But since I have a pretty reasonable answer to share, I might just answer it anyways. But it also contains spoilers, so... yeah.

> Based on what I know about the next arc, it's all about time travel, and yes, the game *Dragon Ball Xenoverse* is all about time travel too, and also the game's sequel, it both featured Future Trunks. If you played the game before, or know a bit about the game. [Future Trunks from Xenoverse and Online](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Future_Trunks#Video_game_stories) works for [Supreme Kai of Time](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Supreme_Kai_of_Time) as her assistant and the head of the [Time Patrol](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Patrol), his job is to mainly fixing distorted timelines.
> [Towa](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Towa) and [Mira](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Towa) were the two major villains that travel through time to destroy the history. Besides that, Towa can cast [dark magic](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Towa%27s_Dark_Magic) on enemies which gives the user pure red eyes and a dark aura, pretty much turning them into demons.
> So, the *evil / black Goku* is probably from an alternate timeline (defeated the heart virus) and been cast by Towa's dark magic, and turn him into her pawn to assist her evil plan. Future Trunks from that timeline fought the evil Goku and was overwhelmed, he barely escaped into the main timeline to ask for help once again.

Though, it's just a theory, I might be wrong, or not even close.

Comment: Oh, So you mean there are now 3 alternate timelines of Universe 7?
1. The one which followed in the anime
2. Trunk's timeline
3. Evil Goku?

Comment: @BhaveshShaha Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: cruncyroll has the Future Trunks arc so you can see. It is Universe 12 I believe.

Comment: Following to see what happened in the anime, this answer doesn't hold the answer to the question anymore, I recommend that this should be changed